# Python: Flags which are inputted into functions from other functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a basic calculator and have a small problem I cant quite get. When you press the number buttons the input box will add the numbers until you then press a math key where the numbers will reset. What I cant work out is, say you put a number in like 8 then hit the inverse key, the output will show 0.125, then when you start typing again it will delete all things in the output window. Here is what I have but isn't working.

```
def button_click(number):
    if Flag == True:
        e.delete(0,END)
        e.insert(0, str(number))
    else:
        Current = e.get()
        e.delete(0,END)
        e.insert(0, str(Current) + str(number))
    global Flag
    Flag = False
```

and for the inv function

```
def button_inv():
    Current = float(e.get())
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, 1/Current)
    global Flag
    Flag = True
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please repair the indentation of first snippet.

Comment: Explain "isn't working". What happens?

Comment: I will get the error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Flag' referenced before assignment

Comment: Hi! Usually when getting exceptions, it is helpful to post the full stack-trace as well. That helps to know on which line the exception happened. Could you add it to your question please?

Comment: Also, I think the problem is you need to put "global Flag" at the start of your function.

Comment: I tried putting Flag at the beginning but then got line 14
    Global Flag
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Is this the full stack trace you were after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your placement of the `global Flag` is wrong, it should be placed at the beginning.

```
def button_click(number):
    global Flag
    if Flag == True:
        e.delete(0,END)
        e.insert(0, str(number))
    else:
        Current = e.get()
        e.delete(0,END)
        e.insert(0, str(Current) + str(number))
    Flag = False
```

and

```
def button_inv():
    global Flag
    Current = float(e.get())
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, 1/Current)
    Flag = True
```

and declare `Flag = False` at the beginning of your code.